# Ubuntu 32-bit, dual monitor very slow

Tags: external-monitor, vga

Older 32-bit laptop running 18.04.

When I plug in an external VGA monitor it slows down abysmally, as in 20+seconds between keystrokes. If I unplug the monitor it works fine again.

External shows the background fine and cursor is normal speed. Everything else is dead slow. Tried several monitors same result.

How can I fix this?

ETA: (had to type this from laptop screen)

```
X-Cinnamon
drm_kms_helper   167936 1 i915
syscopyarea  16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect  16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt    16384 1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops  16384 1 drm_kms_helper
drm 393216 5 i915,drm_kms_helper
00:02:0 compatible VGA conrtoller: intel corp Mobile 945GM/GMS,943/948GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 3)
subsystem: Acer Mobile 945GM/GMS,943/948GML Express Integrated     Graphics Controller
Kernel driver in us: i915
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology center (0x8086)
```

Sorry if any typos, but I think I have it correct.

Comment: Details needed: desktop, video adapter, its driver. Please edit your question to add the following outputs - `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP; lsmod | grep drm; lspci -k | grep -iE "video|3d|vga|graphics" -A2; glxinfo | grep Vendor` .

Comment: Not really sure, but you can try to boot Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS liveusb to check its performance with two monitors. Cinnamon may be to heavy. I will not expect high 2 monitor performance for the intergated video chip from 2000's.

Comment: @N0rbert: OK, thanks. Not sure I wan to spend an hour and half downloading MATE on a whim though. :)

Comment: Cinnamon?  Are you using Ubuntu or Linux Mint? but why such a *heavy* desktop? I would not use a *heavy* desktop on an i386, and would not expect a second monitor to alter performance (*though I've experienced that condition once too*)

Comment: @guiverc Yeah, Ubuntu and I had installed Cinnamon years back, no idea why now. :)

Comment: @N0rbert Could not stand the suspense so set it to download MATE overnight. Boonies DSL is 3mb (that's "Bits") at best. Anyway, MATE did exactly the same. I also tried messing t-with xrandr and setting-up different profiles, but always like wading through mud experience.

Comment: Just curious - what is the model of laptop?